# Excel need to match and paste to an adjacent cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So the formula needs to look at column D IN SHEET 1, go over to sheet 2, if it finds a match in column A, then paste the coordinates in column B into sheet 1 column E.[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rehLP.png)

Comment: Suggest you go watch the video at [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Jeeped, you may use Excel Worksheet `VLOOKUP()` function: enter the following `Formula` into Cell "E2" of the first Worksheet("Sheet1"):

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

and extend it down to the last row with data in Column D. Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options on how to do it.  As jeeped pointed out the VLOOKUP is a great choice for this layout.  Alex's answer has the formula looking at the entire A and B column so you may want to edit that to match the rows of data you have.  Another way of doing that automatically is

```
=vlookup(D2,offset(sheet2!$A$1,0,0,counta(sheet2!A:A),2),2,0)
```

Another method which could be more versatile if your data is layed out differently is:

```
=index(offset(sheet2!$A$1,0,1,counta(sheet2!A:A),1),match(D2,offset(sheet2!$A$1,0,0,counta(sheet2!A:A),1),0)-1)
```

Heck I think even the following would work in your case

```
=offset(sheet2!$A$1,match(D2,offset(sheet2!$A$1,0,0,counta(sheet2!A:A),1),0)-1,1,1,1)
```